# Is it possible to run more than one node on a physical host without full-fat VM?

Tags: docker, arm, arm64

I am planning on running Docker and Swarms on some rPi 3B+'s. My first goal is to test the fault tolerance abilities of RAFT consensus across at least 3 machines so I can simulate failure of a node.

According to:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/

.. a node within the current way of doing things (swarmkit, Docker v18) is a docker machine running on a physical host right under the host's OS, or a "full-fat" VM guest OS > docker machine that runs a layer underneath the physical host.

is it possible to run multiple nodes on a linux machine in parallel without having to do the full-fat VM work?

Since ARM doesn't have hardware virtualization capabilities like x86 platforms, and rPi has a limited amount of computation power, there would be a huge performance hit running VM's in order to have multiple nodes on a single physical host. I'm curious if there's an alternative or if I'm just entirely misunderstanding how this Docker Engine / swarmkit interaction works.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you are just getting into container orchestration, don't bother with swarm. It's basically dead as even docker (the company) has shifted focus to kubernetes. Kubernetes is the most popular solution but ECS (AWS only) is also fairly popular.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. When I was looking at the options, Kubernetes seemed more developed but also more difficult to deploy according to comparisons of the two orchestration frameworks. But I'd rather be using the one that still has a future! The split between the old Docker <1.1.2 + Swarm and the new Docker >1.1.2 + Swarmkit was already confusing enough in their official documentation.

Comment: If you can leverage VirtIO or other paravirtualization technologies, running VM's on a Pi actually isn't really all that much of a performance hit.  The big performance killer on the Pi in most cases is the storage interface.  This isn't to say that you'll get native equivalent performance, but it's still good enough for network simulation (and will probably beat containers for that, as the networking is actually marginally simpler using a VM).

Comment: Yes, the Pi has extremely limited available bandwidth because the bus is shared by network, local storage and the CPU. I'm not doing anything bandwidth intensive but there are reasons I want the GPIO and radio capabilities present for some of my projects though, and being able to deploy them with kubernetes management would be a huge plus.

One option I was considering is using QEMU. The Wikipedia mentioned it now has good support for ARMx64 and the processor inside the Pi. As long as I could run at least 2 x logical nodes per Pi board that would be a huge boon.

Comment: I'm strongly considering using a ROC-RK3328-CC since it claims to not have the conflicted memory controller problem of the Pi. Most benchmarks I can find for storage access say it will perform 10x better or more, so running VM's is less bottlenecked on a given physical board.

The constraint in this situation though is, the roc- boards do not come with WiFi chips onboard so I'd have to buy a hat expansion board for that, or find a USB 3.0 chip that works out of the box with one of the approved OSes for that board. So far I can't find documentation on WiFi drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on jordanm's comment & the fact that both Docker Swarm and Kubernetes orchestration uniformly say a given node has to have either a full-VM or a physical host, I'm going to say it is in fact not possible in either system, but it would be especially fruitless to try doing so with Docker Swarm since it's already a DOA platform.